# Android ripple color applied for focused and hovered states

Tags: android, android-drawable, ripple, rippledrawable, ripple-effect

I'm trying to implement `Button` (`AppCompatButton`) with ripple effect and selector (focused, hovered, disabled etc.). I've created drawable.xml which looks like this:

```
<ripple android:color="#rippleColor">
    <item><shape android:shape="rectangle">...</shape>
    <item>
        <selector>
            <item android:state_enabled="false">
                <shape>...</shape>
            </item>
            <item android:state_focused="true">
                <shape>...</shape>
            </item>
            ...another states...
        </selector>
    <item>
</ripple>
```

This code works, but if use d-pad or cursor navigation, when `Button` is focused or hovered, instead of colors from selector, ripple color is being used.

Comment: Did you try a `MaterialButton`? Just use the `rippleColor` and `backgroundTint`(selector) attributes.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti just tried it. I've used MaterialButton and added only one color for backgroundTint (no selector) and ripple color and the result is the same - when the button became focused/hovered it uses ripple color to highlight button